# python kivy collision detection isn't working

Tags: python, kivy, collision-detection

Im trying to create a game with Python's `Kivy` but my collision detection system isnt working i've tried many different methods on youtube but still no success it either does detect anything or just gives me error messages

```
def collides(self, player, ball2):

    r1x = player.pos[0]
    r1y = player.pos[1]
    r2x = ball2.pos[0]
    r2y = ball2.pos[1]
    r1w = player.size[0]
    r1h = player.size[1]
    r2w = ball2.size[0]
    r2h = ball2.size[1]

    if r1x < r2x + r2w and r1x + r1w > r2x and r1y < r2y + r2h and r1y + r1h > r2y:
        print("True")
        return True
    else:
        return False
        print('False')
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you have to use `print('False')` before `return False` to see this text.

Comment: what object is `player` and `ball`? Kivy's widget has function `.collide_point()` and `.collide_widget()`. See doc: [Widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html)

Comment: BTW: with widget you can also use  `.right` instead of `x + width`, and `.top` instead of `y+height`

Comment: Is there a way I can send you my project so you can look at it because i tried adding more info to my question but it would not let me upload it

Comment: if it is public project then you could keep it on [GitHub](https://github.com/) and put link in comment.

Comment: Thank you!!!( https://github.com/RickSkyyy/TheFalling.git ) here is the project. I've only been coding for less than a month so please forgive me is my code looks a bit offI've been trying to figure out this collision detection thing for a few days so thank you for landing me your time.

Comment: If anyone was unable to edit the file before they should be able to now. I updated the repository and branch.

Comment: I made working code - but I made many changes. I made `class Sprite` similar to `pygame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in `collides` seems OK but rest of code (in repo) doesn't look good.

I took code from repo and first I made many changes to make it cleaner - I made class `Sprite` similar to `pygame.Sprite`

And next I tried use collisions and they work for me.

I keep all balls on list so I can use `for`-loop to work with all ball. And I can add more balls and it will still works the same. And I can remove ball from list when it is "killed".

I also run all with one `schedule_interval`. When I click button then I only change speed `vx` without running another `schedule_interval`. And this way in `update()` I can first I make calculation, next I can check collisions and at the end I can move rect on canvas - and this way `rect` doesn't blik when I have to move it back to previous position (ie. when I detect collision with border).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse, Rectangle, Color
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import Clock, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


# How to play the game: Click left and right to move along the 'x' axis to stop click button to move in the opposite
# direction once, to go faster just repeatedly click the direction you want to go BUT there's a catch the faster
# you are going the harder it is to stop sp be carefull. you can teleport to the other side of the screen but only from
# the right side to the left side

# Objective: Dodge all incoming enemies until you reach the next level

# Level layout: Lvl 1: Space invaders type mode Lvl 2: Platform runner type mode Lvl 3: undecided...

# Goal: Make this game playable both on mobile and pc

class Sprite():
    def __init__(self, x, y, size, color, vx, vy):
        '''Set all values.'''
        
        self.start_x = x
        self.start_y = y
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
        self.rect = None
        #self.alive = True
        
    def create_rect(self):
        '''Execute it in `with canvas:` in `on_size()`.'''
        
        Color(*self.color)
        self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(self.x, self.y), size=(self.size, self.size))
    
    def set_start_pos(self, center_x, center_y):
        '''Move to start position.'''
        
        self.x = center_x + self.start_x
        self.y = center_y + self.start_y
        
    def move(self):
        '''Calculate new position without moving object on `canvas`.'''
        
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy
        
    def draw(self):
        '''Move object on canvas.'''
        
        self.rect.pos = (self.x, self.y)
        
    def check_collision_circle(self, other):
        
        distance = (((self.x-other.x)**2) + ((self.y-other.y)**2)) ** 0.5

        #if distance < (self.size + other.size)/2:
        #    print(True)
        #    return True
        #else:
        #    return False

        return distance < (self.size + other.size)/2:
        
    def check_collision_rect(self, other):

        # code `... and ...` gives `True` or `False`
        # and it doesn't need `if ...: return True else: return False`
        
        return (
            (other.x <= self.x + self.size) and 
            (self.x <= other.x + other.size) and 
            (other.y <= self.y + self.size) and 
            (self.y <= other.y + other.size)
        )
    
class MainCanvas(Widget):
    rec_x = NumericProperty(0)
    inc = dp(3)
    ball_size = dp(35)
    my_player = ObjectProperty(Rectangle)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.player = Sprite(x=-self.ball_size/2, y=145, size=dp(15), vx=dp(0), vy=dp(0), color=(1, .3, .5))
        
        self.balls = [
            Sprite(x=0,    y=-2000, size=dp(15), vx=dp(0), vy=dp(8), color=(1, 0, 0)),
            Sprite(x=100,  y=-1000, size=dp(15), vx=dp(0), vy=dp(5), color=(1, 1, 0)),
            Sprite(x=-200, y=-1000, size=dp(30), vx=dp(0), vy=dp(5), color=(1, 1, 1)),
            Sprite(x=300,  y=-600,  size=dp(15), vx=dp(0), vy=dp(5), color=(1, 1, 1)),
        ]

        with self.canvas:
            for ball in self.balls:
                ball.create_rect()
        
            self.player.create_rect()
            
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60)

    def on_size(self, *args):
        print(f'on_size : {self.width}x{self.height}')
        
        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.set_start_pos(self.center_x, self.center_y)
            
        self.player.set_start_pos(self.center_x, self.center_y)

        self.rec_x = self.player.x

    def update(self, dt):
        # all in one function to control if it check collision after move, and draw only after all calculations 
        
        # --- moves (without draws) ---  
        
        self.player_move(dt)
        
        # move green rectangle below player
        self.rec_x = self.player.x
        
        self.ball_move(dt)

        # --- collisions (without draws) ---
        
        live_balls = []
        
        for ball in self.balls:
            if self.player.check_collision_rect(ball):
            #if self.player.check_collision_circle(ball):
                print('killed')
                
                # hide
                #ball.set_start_pos(self.center_x, self.center_y)
                #ball.draw()
                
                # or remove from canvas
                self.canvas.remove(ball.rect)
            else:
                live_balls.append(ball)
                
        self.balls = live_balls
        
        # --- draws ---

        self.player.draw()

        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.draw()

    def on_left_click(self):
        print('Left Clicked')
        self.player.vx -= self.inc

    def on_right_click(self):
        print('Right Clicked')
        self.player.vx += self.inc

    def ball_move(self, dt):
        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.move()

            if ball.y + ball.size > self.height:
                ball.set_start_pos(self.center_x, self.center_y)

    def player_move(self, dt):
        self.player.move()
        
        # moving left and stop on screen border
        if self.player.vx < 0 and self.player.x < 0:
            self.player.x = 0
            self.player.vx = 0

        # moving right and jump to left side when leave screen
        if self.player.vx > 0 and self.width < self.player.x:
            self.player.x = 0

class TheFalling(App):
    pass

app = TheFalling()
app.run()
#app.stop()
app.root_window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much this means a lot, and thanks for the explanation. I'll try to write code more carefully in the future to avoid problems like this now I can carry on with the game finally.